# iptables: Allowing connections initiated from inside

Tags: linux, iptables, debian-squeeze

My **debian squeeze** servers (*not in a state to upgrade*) are currently using the following rule to **allow the connections that are initiated from the same server and later connected to random ports from the destination**.

> `-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Since this uses **connection tracking** module and there is a lot of connections, It creates a bottleneck.

Is there any alternative option to allow these connections which are
connecting to random ports, which are initially started from the same
server?

Comment: I **very** much doubt that it has created a bottleneck.  Before you go looking for alternatives to the standard kernel, **and** lead us into [an X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you show us the evidence for the underlying problem you're trying to solve, here?

Comment: @MadHatter , The application is unavailable to new users once the connection reaches a limit. The table gets filled up with all the EST connections. This brings huge service unavailability. Loading connection module is a cost I can't afford since I have seen the bottleneck it creates and connections dropping because of it.

Comment: But `--state ESTABLISHED` is usually only used to filter *inbound* connections, and thus wouldn't apply to connections to your application unless the rules were very badly sequenced.  I repeat that I don't yet accept that your problem is what you think it is, and again urge you to lay out for us the *actual* problem, and the *actual* evidence thereof.